# ISOString Date format in XSLT

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt-1.0

I have the below XML input file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:Bonger xmlns:ns3="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.Bonger" xmlns:ns2="http://NEXSTEP.Schemas.NexstepTypes">
  <ROUTE_RECORD>
    <ns2:SENDER Sender_code="BO_SERVER"/>
    <ns2:RECEIPIENT Receipient_code="MASTER"/>
    <ns2:OverAllStatus>NY</ns2:OverAllStatus>
  </ROUTE_RECORD>
  <MESSAGE_RECORD>
    <InsertChange>
      <Message>
        <ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet>
          <ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt>2021-08-09+02:00</ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt>
          <ns2:OpprettetKl>15:13:14.636+02:00</ns2:OpprettetKl>
          <ns2:EndretAv>ADMIN</ns2:EndretAv>
        </ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet>
      </Message>
    </InsertChange>
  </MESSAGE_RECORD>
</ns3:Bonger>
```

Using a transformer I need to use both OpprettetTidspunkt and OpprettetKl (both date and time) and need to output something like <MSG_DATE>2021-08-09T10:48:15.057<MSG_DATE>

Please note that I need to output the MSG_DATE as ISOString format

Any ideas??

Comment: Please show the **exact** output you need to get in the given example. Specifically, how do you want to handle the `+02:00` offset.

Comment: @michael.hor257k something like this would do <MSG_DATE>2021-06-16T08:32:17 +02:00</MSG_DATE>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the outputs you show make no sense when compared to your input. Assuming that the correct output in the given example is actually:

```
MSG_DATE>2021-08-09T15:13:14.636+02:00</MSG_DATE>
```

you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns3:Bonger">
    <!-- ... -->
    <MSG_DATE>
        <xsl:variable name="mod" select="MESSAGE_RECORD/InsertChange/Message/ns2:OpprettetEndretSlettet"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($mod/ns2:OpprettetTidspunkt, 1, 10)"/>
        <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$mod/ns2:OpprettetKl"/>
    </MSG_DATE>
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is working as expected. Thanks alot for you help. Much Appreciated